# Detecting unknown number of simultaneous taps

Tags: ios, gesture, tap, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm working on an app that will be used by two to four people using a single iPad. Each of them will be tapping with one or more fingers. They are not coordinated with each other. So gestures could be recognized as any number of taps. Do I need to create separate gesture recognizers for each number of fingers scenario? I will also need to know the locations of each of the taps.

I know the iPad recognizes a maximum of 11 touches, and this app will probably run into that limit. So if I can avoid having to code 11 separate recognizers, that would be great.

Comment: Based on what it sounds like you're doing it may be better to use custom touch handling instead of boxed UIGestureRecognizers. That being said, You may be able to get away with a single UITapGestureRecognizer, some combination of delegate methods, and an explicit ending of the gesture in the callback so that holding your finger on the screen doesn't hijack the gesture.

Comment: Thanks. I suspect writing a piano simulator app would run into the very same issues I would be dealing with, if that helps to visualize the scenario.

Comment: @Ryan, can you explain what you mean by "and an explicit ending of the gesture in the callback so that holding your finger on the screen doesn't hijack the gesture"?